# Count missing function arguments in PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to count missing arguments in a PHP function? I want to do this:

```
// I have this
function foo($param1, $param2, $param3) {
    // I need some sort of argument counter
}

foo("hello", "world");
```

When I use the foo function like above, I want a way to find out that not all arguments are used.

Either by counting all arguments and comparing to get_defined_vars(), or by using a function that gives me the count of missing arguments.

Edit:
I need the method to stop running if some of the arguments are missing when error_reporting is turned of.

```
if(!foo($param)) { echo "Couldn't Foo!"; }
```

Comment: Test if those variables are null, if it is then it's 'missing'.

Comment: It's the first result in a [trivial search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=php+count+arguments). Please do some web searching before reaching for the _Ask question_ button `:)`.

Comment: You don't understand my need. I have googled my issue :) I have about 30 arguments, so doing a manual check isn't what I want.

Comment: obviously you're doing it wrong. consider a parameter object/array or something like this. also read about how php treats arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this super-dynamical, use reflection to get the expected parameter count and compare that number to what func_num_args() returns:

```
function foo($p1 = null, $p2 = null, $p3 = null) {
    $refl = new ReflectionFunction(__FUNCTION__);

    $actualNumArgs = func_num_args();
    $expectedNumArgs = $refl->getNumberOfParameters();

    $numMissingArgs = $expectedNumArgs - $actualNumArgs;

    // ...
```

Comment: This is nice but I can't get it to work within my method/function (within a class).

Will this work within a method?

Comment: @RAH You will need to use `$refl = new ReflectionMethod($this, __METHOD__);` to get this working for a method. Apart from that, it's the same.

Comment: Sorry, you cannot use `__METHOD__` there, use `__FUNCTION__` instead. See http://codepad.viper-7.com/xznugY

Answer (score 3):

Use [`func_num_args()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to know the count of missing arguments, this won't help me :(

Comment: The number of required arguments minus the number of given arguments should be what you want - and I think you know how many arguments are required?

Comment: Yes, I know, and it's 37. But if I want to edit the code later it would be nice to not count them manually.

My question is simple. Is there a function that counts missing arguments in a function in PHP? :)

- If not, then I have to count manually.

Comment: You may want to use some kind of dependency injection!

Answer (score 1):

Calling a function with insufficient arguments will throw an error. If you need to allow calling a function with less arguments you need to define them with default values in the function declaration and test for the default values to see which have been omitted.

Something like this (**IMPROVED AGAIN**):

```
function foo () {

  // Names of possible function arguments
  // This replaces the list of arguments in the function definition parenthesis
  $argList = array('param1', 'param2', 'param3');

  // Actual function arguments
  $args = func_get_args();

  // The number of omitted arguments
  $omittedArgs = 0;

  // Loop the list of expected arguments
  for ($i = 0; isset($argList[$i]); $i++) {
    if (!isset($args[$i])) { // The argument was omitted - this also allows you to skip arguments with NULL since NULL is not counted as set
      // increment the counter and create a NULL variable in the local scope
      $omittedArgs++;
      ${$argList[$i]} = NULL;
    } else {
      // The argument was passed, create a variable in the local scope
      ${$argList[$i]} = $args[$i];
    }
  }

  // Function code goes here
  var_dump($omittedArgs);

}
```

This is slightly counter intuitive to other people who maybe maintaining the code - the argument list is now maintained as an array of strings instead of a list of function arguments, but apart from that is is completely dynamic and achieves what you want.

Comment: @mightyuhu It gets even weirder after testing and playing, check out the edit... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, the simplest solution may be default parameters:

```
function foo($param1 = null, $param2 = null, $param3 = null) {
  if ($param3 !== null) {
    // 3 params are specified
  } else if ($param2 !== null) {
    // 2 params are specified
  } else if ($param1 !== null) {
    // 1 param is specified
  } else {
    // no param is specified
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have about 30 arguments :P

Comment: What about refactoring? Such an amount of values should only be stored in an array, maybe in fields.

Comment: Hehe, I'm building this über tight class, I need it to work this way - at least I think I need it this way.

The best solution for now is to count the arguments and compare them to func_num_args(), but I want it to be dynamic :)

Thanks.

Comment: Consider posting your code at [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You can use built-in php functions:

array of arguments:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

number of arguments:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php

get argument from array
http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php